# Characteristic polynomial for the composition of a linear transformation with itself

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, characteristic-polynomial

Suppose I know the characteristic polynomial of the linear transformation $T$, can the characteristic polynomial of $L= T\circ T$ be obtained?

At the moment I don't know any theorem or result that can help me

Comment: Your title is for the composition of two different linear transformations and the content of your question is for the same transformation...

Comment: Although likely you know what about this problem is interesting or challenging to you, the value of sharing that context with your Readers may not be evident to you (as a relatively new user).  A few words about what prompted the Question helps illuminate what kind of Answers will be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, yes. Let $n$ be the dimension of $T$. The characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\sigma_k(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)x^{n-k}$$ where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$ denote the eigenvalues of $T$ and $\sigma_k$ is the $k$-th elementary symmetric polynomial in the $\lambda_i$. The characteristic polynomial of $T^2$ is $$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \sigma_k(\lambda_1^2,\ldots,\lambda_n^2)x^{n-k}.$$ By the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials, each coefficient above is expressible as a polynomial in $\sigma_1(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n),\ldots,\sigma_n(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)$. That is, the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $T^2$ can be obtained from the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $T$.

P.S. You might want to look into [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities).

Comment: is that recently I came across a problem in which they gave me the eigenvalues ​​of the linear transformation $T$ and asked me to obtain the characteristic polynomial of $T\circ T$

Comment: @user19872448 That's a special case, since every eigenvalue corresponds to a factor of the characteristic polynomial. And if you know an eigenvalue of $T$, then you get an eigenvalue of $T^2$ for free.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos then, assuming that $t(x))$ is the characteristic polynomial of $T$, to obtain that of $T\circ T$ it is correct to take $t(x)^2$ or $t(t(x))$

Comment: @user19872448 If you add your actual problem to the question, I or someone else could answer it.